# Does the EMR Java api expose counters

Tags: java, emr, amazon-emr

I cannot find a way to access counters using the Amazon EMR Java client. Is it available? Do I have to use cloud watch?

If there are no built in ways to access counters, what would be a good approach? The first thing that comes to mind is flushing it periodically to an S3 file, but I don't like it since I need to pass credentials (I could not find a way to access the credentials used to start the job).

Any ideas or directions?